# My logic is failing me (C++, nslookup, char comparison)

Tags: c++, char, logic, popen

I'm cycling through the responses I'm getting from issuing the "nslookup [IP]" command at a shell, using the C++ _popen pipe magic.

As you may know (try it from a terminal... Windows command prompt may output differently than another OS; I'm using Windows 7), an nslookup query will return something like:

```
C:\MyApps>nslookup 8.8.8.8
Server:  dns.mydomain.com
Address:  192.168.200.15

Name:    google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8
```

Here's my code (the important snippet):

```
vector<string> IPAddresses;
// [...] some code to populate IP Addresses into that vector [...]

char buff[512];
for(int x=0;x<IPAddresses.size();x++)
{
    cmd = "nslookup " + IPAddresses[x];
    FILE *fpipe = _popen(cmd.c_str(),"r");
    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fpipe)!=NULL)
    {
        //DEBUG CODE HERE
    }
}
```

Now check my "DEBUG CODE" examples and their outputs (noting that the "cannot find IP: Non-existent domain" error is normal when there's no DNS record present):

```
if(buff[0]=='N') cout<<buff;
```

Output:

```
Name:   computer1.mydomain.com
Name:   computer2.mydomain.com
*** dns.mydomain.com can't find 192.168.200.55: Non-existent domain
Name:   computer3.mydomain.com
*** dns.mydomain.com can't find 192.168.200.122: Non-existent domain
```

Debug code 2:

```
if(buff[0]=='*') cout<<buff;
```

Output:

```
*** dns.mydomain.com can't find 192.168.200.55: Non-existent domain
*** dns.mydomain.com can't find 192.168.200.122: Non-existent domain
```

How can the non-existent domain errors pop up when I'm looking for buff[0] to be 'N'?  In fact, it's showing up in both debug examples, so my program thinks that char is both 'N' and '*'???

Comment: I suspect you're getting `stdout` output from `popen` but error/diagnostic messages to `stderr` are still going directly to the console.

Comment: If that were the case, it would output the whole DNS lookup error, right?  Not just the third line of a non-existent domain error?

Comment: I don't know - it's Windows so nothing is certain, but my best guess is that it's a stdout/stderr thing - you can test the theory from your command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those two strings are probably being output not because your code is printing it, but because `nslookup` is writing them to `stderr`, which your program does not capture (and is thus mixed with your output).

Comment: I tested your theory by removing the debug code altogether, and sure enough!  I still got those messages!  Must be stderr

Comment: Any tips on how to capture the stderr with my existing code snippet there?

Comment: You can append " 2>&1" to the command, which will redirect `stderr` to `stdout`.

Comment: I just figured out the 2> trick as you were commenting, haha.  Thanks very much!  Will make your response the 'answer' when it allows me (5 mintues or so)